# how to change the value of the checkbox column in a datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with a CheckBox column.  I show a popup if the CheckBox check is removed and ask the user if he want to remove the check.  If the user click no, I want the checkbox to be checked again. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a lot with it but it seem not to work. So I've changed the check box to an imagebutton. That imagebutton has a checked and unchecked image shown each time the user click so that is the best solution. Also, much easier event to handle and you can use the itemcommand event which is much easier to deal with.

Comment: thanks me for great help :) and thanks to all people how had given an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')" />
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I need. I have a pop called when the check is removed. What I need is to change the value of the check box column in the datagrid

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a Javascript/JQuery popup to display the confirmation message (using an *onchange* or *onclick* event).  To achieve what you need, capture a reference to the element before displaying the popup, in your event handler.

```
function handleCheckboxChange() {
    var clickedElement = $(this);

    // display popup confirmation
    // ...
    // if user clicks "no", use this line:
    clickedElement.attr("checked", true);
}
```

Comment: This is a good method and a good way to implement the confirm box but the problem I use ajax toolkit and it's popup control. And the code must be handled in the code behind.